# How to make a model shaded with only two colors?

Tags: freestyle

I haven't found any tutorials on cartoon rendering. What I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

By the way, I know freestyle is not realistic rendering, but I can notice some light bouncing. if that is so, how can I achieve that effect?

Comment: "I don't care" = "whatever the approach is"

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9068/599

Answer (score 5):

Freestyle only renders lines. For the shading, you might try *Toon shading*:

[image]

[image]