# How can I achieve a Japanese style cell animation toon shader look in Blender?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Here are my examples.

Edit// Here is a video showing what I want exactly, how "shaders" and "renderer" should work.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQLgn9-xqQc

notice how easy it is to set the shadows on the character in the video here?

[image: Wireframe with Basic texture]

[image: After shader is applied]

Somehow they have controls over the shading, and normals. And the shader draws smooth lines around the edges. Here are more examples.

[image]

Animation:

https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/916984184035360768

This here is actually created in blender.
https://orig00.deviantart.net/f78a/f/2015/056/9/e/untitled_by_keiichiisozaki-d8jfztd.gif

I actually think it's better than most of the other ones, I don't know what tricks he used, or if it holds up in full 3D animation though.

The others are all pretty much 3DS MAX Pencil+ plugin.

here's some more examples even.

I would like to know, what kind of settings, what kind of stuff I should be looking for, to copy this style with blender, or if anybody pro enough to create a short tutorial it would be amazing!

Here are a few more. Supposedly, this style is "easy" if you have the 500$ 3DS Max plugin...

Anybody know here?
https://entry.cgworld.jp/column/toei_main1.jpg

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33871/is-there-really-a-way-to-make-a-true-toon-shader-material-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33871/is-there-really-a-way-to-make-a-true-toon-shader-material-in-cycles