# How to create a "Airbrush-like" Shading Material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

How could I make a material out of the following picture?
[image]

and also the Glossy one?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> EEVEE only answer!

[image: final]

As it's hard to create such material in Cycles as you posted above, it's fairly easy to achieve it in EEVEE (for now only in Blender 2.8 Alpha 2).

[image: anm]

For Cycles answer you can check here: [Is there really a way to make a true toon shader material in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33871/is-there-really-a-way-to-make-a-true-toon-shader-material-in-cycles) Many nice examples provided.

### Node setup and overview.

[image: nodes]

We are using here **Specular BSDF** to get simple shading and convert it to colour through **Shader to RGB**. From it we are making two "channels" for separated highlights and shadow using Color Ramps.

After that we are combining those "channels" with **Noise** and then mixing them to get final "mask".

At the end we have **Color Ramp** with our colours. From left: shadow, main and highlight. And connect it to **Emission shader**.

Optionally you can add some **Contrast** or **Saturation**, or anything to improve result.

Comment: I might use Eevee in Blender 2.80 Alpha 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in Cycles (Eevee).

Since you need to break up that blue color with spots it better not to use the principled shader. So I just took 2 diffuse nodes with the blue and green color and used a gradient texture with a color ramp to control to fall off.

Mix that together with a glossy node for the shine. (If you want to take the shine off, connect the 2nd mix shader directly to the output ("no gloss")).

Then play with all the nodes I circled. Those will control how big the spots are and how you want the falloff to look.

Hope this helps a little.

[image]

This one I just added a bump node (circled) to give you the bumpy look if thats what you are after.

[image]