# Can stippling be used to create a 3D model?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I'm following along this thread:

[How can stipple shading be replicated in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143884/how-can-stipple-shading-be-replicated-in-blender/144160#144160)

But the .blender files don't seem to work so I'm creating from scratch.  Does anyone know offhand it it is possible to use this to create 3D models of these?  Preferably, what I'm trying to do is turn a watertight 3D model into a series of spheres that would then be able to be assigned color or whatever.  I have access to a Stratasys Polyjet printer so I would be able to encase these dots in clear. I just want to know if this process in Blender is only for visual only.

Comment: Hello, I'm afraid all the techniques showcased in this post are for visual only, you won't easily be able to 3D print the models, unless you bake the textures and use that as a real displacement, but even then I highly doubt the resulting mesh will be fit for 3D printing without a severe retopology work. Could you add a screenshot of a real world object you want to replicate ?

Comment: Seconded, would love to know more about what you are trying to do.  I also have a stratasys polyjet printer and have made some objects that may be similar to what you are talking about