# How can I combine a Gradient and Noise Texture?

Tags: node-editor, shader-nodes

I'm trying to recreate this texture:
So far I'm able to make a Gradient Texture on the object, and I'm able to apply a Noise Texture but I'm not able to combine both. How can I do that?

[image: node graph]

[image: grain pic]

Comment: See also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/218498/35559 ... :D

Comment: woot same picture XD

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Mix Color`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/color/mix.html) node under *Add > Color > Mix Color*, but you can also opt to render with *Cycles* without *Denoise* and a low *Samples* count, so you can get a grainy output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could mix a *ColorRamp* with the same *ColorRamp* but affected by a *Color > Bright/Contrast* that you darken, with a *Noise Texture* as Factor, this way you would create some color grains:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added a "Mix" node between the gradient and the noise (or in my case, musgrave) texture, and the ColorRamp node. In my case I wanted the texture itself to be colorized, rather than a gradient of colors with texture laid over it. I also used "diffuse BSDF" instead of the "Principled BSDF" that is put there by default (at the advice of one guide, can't remember which). This seemed to do the trick. I managed to get a gradient running from the center of a circular plane (quadratic sphere gradient), of several colors in the pattern of a musgrave texture out to the edge.

This project was an expansion of the "mushroom in a bottle" tutorial by 3D GreenHorn, which did not deal with textures or shader nodes. So I had to do a lot of other research to come to this setup that worked for me.

[image: Screenshot of a Blender 3D project involving mushrooms and some dirt in a bottle. The dirt is selected, and the shader node section at the bottom of the page is showing the material for the top face of the dirt, which is arranged to produce a gradient of colors in a particular pattern from the center of a circular plane towards the edges, starting with dark green in the middle and fading to brown at the edge.]