# How can I make a glossy finish and an anodized finish (rough but shiny finish)?

Tags: materials, texturing

I am creating a few different Apple products, but having issues getting that MacBook Pro rough anodized aluminum finish look and the high-gloss iPhone type of finish.

Here is an example of the anodized finish I'm wanting to create for the MacBook Pro:

[image]

Here is the high-gloss finish I'd like to have for my iPhone:

[image]

I tried taking a picture of a MacBook Pro and layering that image on top of my model, but that doesn't quite work. Does anyone have suggestions on how to create these two type of textures?

Comment: Which renderer are you using? Blender Internal or Cycles? Also a photo or a link to a picture of what you are trying to accomplish would be helpful.

Comment: I have tried Blender Render and Blender Cycles. I then import a photo into Blender. The photo is saved onto my computer.

Comment: Ok, do you have any preference for a renderer? I guess my comment was a bit unclear. What I meant was it would be helpful if you added the photo to your question. When you edit your question, click on the image icon above the text box or press [Crtl+G] to add an image.

Comment: I haven't found an image that I am super excited about, but tried using this: https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1sk8ib5oXnnuB10W_fhvn9G1DFcnB8zMdSA8BeeRnJ3s7blGRnQ  Thanks so much!!

Comment: This was for the rough texture... I don't have anything for the glossy finish!

Comment: What about using a rough glossy shader in cycles?

Comment: @gandalf3 how would I go about doing this?

Comment: In cycles, add a new material, click on the drop down labeled diffuse, select glossy, and then increase the roughness.

Comment: @gandalf3 Okay, so I tried this, but for some reason it adds a fuzzy texture on the other objects that are not selected! Any suggestions?

Comment: Changing a material will affect all objects that use it, even if they are not selected. To un-assign a material from an object, click the little X icon in the materials panel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a glossy shader.

Even with just a single glossy shader you should be able to get an effect similar to your reference images, but you may [also want to mix in a bit of diffuse shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3594/599):

[image]

[image]

Note that the way your scene is lit will affect the result a lot, especially with glossy materials. For example, I used a mesh light above the "iphone" to give that highlight:

[image]

See [Whiter white in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6850/599) for some examples.
Also remember that the surrounding objects will affect reflections as well.

Comment: where did you get the wood floor texture?

Comment: @David [CG textures](http://www.cgtextures.com/textures.php?t=browse&q=14119) (I can't remember which one exactly).

Comment: Ok thanks, from CGtextures there is a good chance I already have it.

Answer (score 5):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to create but this is my guess.

1. If your object doesn't already have a UV map, create one

   - There are a few automatic ways of doing this. You could use smart project but in this case I am going to use the Cube Project for the iPhone.
2. Add an Anisotropic material to your object.
3. In the material editor add an Input -> Tangent node and set the *Direction* to *UV Map* than select your UV map
4. Connect the Tangent node output to the Anisotropic node's Tangent input.

   [image]

---

[image]

Comment: Hi @Vader, are using an image with this?

Comment: @user3356901 no, no image needed.

Comment: thanks for your help... However, when rendering, it appears that other parts of the mesh that are not selected become rough. It also changes the color. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is a second question... This doesn't appear to let me use that white/silver color. It will only display gray. However, when selecting a darker color like green or blue, it will display the color. Are there any suggestions on fixing this? Thanks!

Comment: you need a bright lighter. Check this out http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/whiter-white-in-cycles